# Address unavailable for UrlFetchApp.fetch in Google Apps Script

Tags: api, google-apps-script, google-sheets

First of all, many thanks to Google for the awesome Google Apps Script!

I am currently designing a Google Sheets ad-on with a API service named CryptoCompare. So far it has always worked out quite well. But suddenly I get the error "Address unavailable". I tried different endpoints, new API keys and even new Google Sheets. But nothing works.

This simple call fails:

```
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/blockchain/list');
```

Btw: Other APIs (such as Coinbase, Bittrex, etc.) work perfectly!

Need help, Matthias.

Answer (score 0):

*Solved*

The problem was blocked Google IP addresses on the part of the operator! There is no way around contacting the operator directly or switching to another service - there is no workaround.

Btw: Thanks CryptoCompare for the excellent support!