# Google App Script UrlFetchApp.fetch throwing a Address unavailable error

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, urlfetch

I am trying to fetch some data from https://www1.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/option_chain/optionKeys.jsp?segmentLink=17&instrument=OPTIDX&symbol=NIFTY&date=30JUL2020  and https://www.nseindia.com/api/option-chain-indices?symbol=NIFTY with proper headers as below.

```
function test() {
    var header = {
        "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate",
        "accept-language": "en-US,en-GB;q=0.9,en-IN;q=0.8,en;q=0.7",
        "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.138 Safari/537.36",
        "cookie": "98B95329E65F98755B7610E8CDEE5E14~n6C7kQLJeDl9L38ZzFTbrfwqstEHxD7Y8Nv6sV2L29QkN2c653MhVx1KgZwl7AQOVOSETOCMpsaGJiPiACRh24FRuvBSkbw8sX+PO+BAUcHA0iySVToapydDjt9vdJ7KmxMXQF9EekFYMnKRwCDSUzxSSPKX6ox2ur6hMg9vWXE="
    };

    //  have tried below way as well
    //  var options={
    //    "headers" : header,
    //  }

    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://www.nseindia.com/", header);
    //  var resp1=response.getContentText();    
    Logger.log(response);
}
```

I have tried using postman and I was able to fetch data correctly even excel advanced pull data from web works. The cookie value is set under bm_sv in the request header and needs to be updated from the website to code every half a day or so.

Not sure what am I missing here.

Comment: Nope I just go to site view request header for bm_sv cookie value and update the value in my code.

Comment: I did not get your question. From what I understood do nse websites returns same value then answer is yes it responds with set-cookie header

Comment: As madhurjya mentioned, the second argument needs to be `params`, not `header`. See [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app). You can pass a `headers` object within params. Also, if this site relies on setting the `user-agent` header, that [is not possible with UrlFetchApp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15067462/urlfetch-with-custom-user-agent-string)

Comment: I have already tried {headers : header} still no luck. I can see from postman that even if user agent is unchecked I can fetch the data but the main catch here is that cookie value

Comment: Might be due to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59989765/address-unavailable-for-urlfetchapp-fetch-in-google-apps-script) Even the homepage is not accessible via apps script. I have no problems accessing other websites.

Comment: umm chances for this are low as I used to work using importHtml normally before then nse introduced this cookie thing and everything changed.

Comment: Would appreciate if you can share solution if you have found @Aniket

Comment: i have also the same issue. whenever i try to run the app script it always return timeout error